# How Create clicker game in unity 3d for mobiles?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to create 2d clicker game in unity. the concept of game is pretty simple there is four 2x2 grid images on canvas and this images shuffles randomly user have to click on thief image
so I want to know is there tutorial for this concept I have to follow please suggest me if anyone knows related tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

The main goals of your projet are into:

- Random behavior https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html
- UI events https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-events-and-event-triggers

Maybe this tutorial is what you are looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTJyJvHZZ1I